# Como aplicar un COUNT a la siguiente sentencia MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, mysqli

Me ocupa lo siguiente:
Tengo esta sentencia SQL

```
SELECT SUM(billetera.monto) AS monto_a_favor, users.*
FROM billetera
INNER JOIN users ON billetera.id_usuario=users.id
WHERE monto_a_favor > 0 AND billetera.status = 1 GROUP BY id
```

Pero me gustaria aplicar con el uso de otra sentencia SQL obtener el resultado de `COUNT(*)` de mi sentencia. Se me complica porque no se como plantear que cuente este tipo de datos cruzados.

Comment: ¿Qué quieres contar? Revisa [mysqli_affected_rows()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.affected-rows.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te entendí bien me parece que esto puede servirte:

```
select count(*)
from
(select sum(billetera.monto) as monto_a_favor, users.*
 from billetera
 inner join users on billetera.id_usuario = users.id
 where monto_a_favor > 0 and billetera.status = 1 group by id) tabla
```

Aquí lo que se hace es aplicar tu consulta original y sobre esta aplicar otro **select**, de esta forma se trataran los resultados que devuelve tu consulta original como si se tratase de una tabla, ya que en esencia una tabla y un **select** son un conjunto de registros. Al hacer esto aplicamos un **count(*)** que nos devolverá el total de registros devueltos por tu consulta original.

Comment: Sigo tu sugerencia pero MySQL da el siguiente error `#1248 - Cada tabla derivada debe tener su propio alias`

Comment: @JoseMHerreraV ese error te ocurre pq debes darle un alias a la subconsulta, le puse  como alias el nombre "tabla", revisa lo nuevo q puse